# How to write media query for this grid layout

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, grid-layout

I want to use media queries on a grid layout below for smaller screens like mobile and tablet but it doesn't apply properly when I try to use them. the full code for the grid layout page can be found: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lighting/2uptxj9v/4/)

the  main container is like this:

```
.page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 55px calc(100vh - 55px); 
  grid-template-columns: 40vh auto;
  grid-template-areas: "header header" 
                       "nav content";
}
```

It works well on the pcs and laptops but in smaller screens despite using a code like:

```
@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .page {
    grid-template-areas:
      "header"
      "content"
      "nav";
  }

}
```

I still get no results. I also tried to reduce `grid-template-columns: 40vh auto;`, `40vh` to something like `10vh` but still, on tablets, the navigation menu is blocking my view and I can't see the content. I wanna have a smaller header and navigation on the tablet screen so I can see the whole page and on a mobile screen, I wanna put navigation under the content and have something like the media query I wrote above.
any tips?

Answer (score 0):

think you shouldn't use auto at grid-template-columns

try this code may help you:

```css
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(400px, 1fr));
  gap: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
```

make sure to change it by your like and change it in smaller screen also

Answer (score 0):

You may simply swap from `grid` to `flex` and reset `order` on `.nav` to send it behind `.content` : https://jsfiddle.net/wze7u5sn/

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {/* break point from your question  , reset it to your needs */
  body {
    overflow: initial;
  }

  .page,
  .content .grid-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .nav {
    order: 2;
  }

  article {
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

---

when you do :

```
@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .page {
    grid-template-areas:
      "header"
      "content"
      "nav";
  }

}
```

You forget to reset `grid-template-columns: 40vh 1fr ;` to `grid-template-columns:1fr;` to have a single column, idem for the `grid-template-rows` you do not reset either.

Also, you probably meant `(max-width:400px)` to filter small screens below 401px.